CRM_Extension_Exception: Invalid extension key: "tellafriend" on upgrade to 5.76.1
I just upgraded from 5.74.4 to 5.76.1 (drupal 7) and got this error:
CRM_Extension_Exception: Invalid extension key: "tellafriend" in <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Upgrades.php on line 125
Exception trace
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Extension_Upgrades::sortKeys()  <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Upgrades.php:125
1   CRM_Extension_Upgrades::getActiveKeys() <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Upgrades.php:107
2   CRM_Extension_Upgrades::getActiveUpgraders()    <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Upgrades.php:42
3   CRM_Extension_Upgrades::hasPending()    <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:798
4   CRM_Upgrade_Form::enqueueExtUpgrades()  <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:101
5   CRM_Queue_Task->run()   <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:255
6   CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext() <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:36
7   CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:93
8   CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call()   <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:38
9   CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:292
10  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()  <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
11  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()  <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
12  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()   <mysitepath>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:470
13  civicrm_invoke()    <mysitepath>/includes/menu.inc:527
14  menu_execute_active_handler()   <mysitepath>/index.php:21
15  {main}  

I went to the extension page and disabled this extension and reran the upgrade.  So far OK.  I have 3 sites and double-checked before upgrading the next one that this extension was not there either on the extension page nor in the civicrm_extension table.  Then I did the upgrade.  Same error.  It looks like the upgrade added this extension to civicrm_extensions (the id column is the highest number) .  So it looks like the upgrade script adds this extension and then complains that the code is not present.
Aside from the inconvenience, can I expect any issues?

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30872. It will be fixed in the next release.
